# Difference in having Sigmoid activation function instead of linear activation and using sigmoid in loss

Tags: tensorflow, loss-function, softmax, sigmoid

I am fairly new to the loss-functions and I have a 800 binary classification problem (meaning 800 neurons at the output that are not effected by eachother - probablity of each is 0 or 1). Now looking at the Documentations from: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits

It seems that it uses "logits" which are the outputs of the network with a linear activation function and the Sigmoid (needed for the binary classification) is applied in the loss-function.

I am looking at the loss-function for the soft-max activation and similar approach is applied. I am wondering why the activation function is not added to the network outputs and the loss function receives the linear outputs (logits) and in the loss function activation is applied.

Comment: No big reason. The sigmoid is used in the loss 1) to save you one step elsewhere 2) to make sure every input to the loss is normalized thus between (0,1).

Comment: @greeness The application of the linear logits made problems in the loss function that are discussed in the help file mentioned in the question that could be prevented. I need to take the Sigmoid when deploying the model so I believe it does not save me anything. 2) it is not normalized, the inputs to the loss-function can be negative as the same help file specifies.

Comment: if you don't need that convenience (actually a pain for you), simply use other pre-defined loss (`tf.losses.log_loss `) or make one for your self. :)

Comment: I see, thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No big reason. The sigmoid is used in the loss

- to save you one step elsewhere
- to make sure every input to the loss is normalized thus between (0,1).

if you don't need that convenience (actually a pain for you), simply use other pre-defined loss (`tf.losses.log_loss`) or make one for your self. :)

Answer (score 1):

Naive application of sigmoid/softmax and cross-entropy is numerically unstable. This is due to the `exp` in the sigmoid and the `log` in the softmax. You can run into issues with over/underflow which could result in things like `log(0)` being taken (which would result in `-inf`). To avoid this, the cross-entropy functions use a "smarter" formulation based directly on the logits, exploiting the fact that `log(exp(x)) == x`. You should always use these functions to avoid numerical problems. If you need the actual probabilities elsewhere, you can still just apply sigmoid/softmax at those points.

Comment: I had the problem of log(0) and that is why I looked into the tensorflow implementation of these functions. The tf.losses.log_loss mentioned by @greeness has a epsilon to remedy the issues too. It seems they implemented both.

Answer (score 0):

The very simple explanation is it's usage in output: sigmoid is used basically for binary classification by treating values from 0 to 1 as probability of primary class, and linear is used for regression problems.